# Gdx Texture resize not displaying

Tags: java, libgdx

The specific tools.png texture is not displaying

Tools.png and TopBanner.png are both in my assets folder and are valid files
Here is my resize function, which works on every other png except tool and my create and render functions

```java
public Texture resize(String path, int width1, int height1){
        Texture final_texture;
        Pixmap TL1 = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(path));
        Pixmap TL2 = new Pixmap(width1, height1, TL1.getFormat());
        TL2.drawPixmap(TL1,
                0, 0, TL1.getWidth(), TL1.getHeight(),
                0, 0, TL2.getWidth(), TL2.getHeight()
        );
        final_texture = new Texture(TL2);
        TL1.dispose();
        TL2.dispose();
        return final_texture;
    }
```

```java
public void create () {
    //there are other things here too but dont pertain to tools
    tools = resize("tools.png", 200, 200);

    TLArrow = resize("TLArrow.png", width*5/4, height/8);
}
```

```java
public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0/255f, 255/255f, 140/255f, 1);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(tools,500, 500);
        batch.draw(TLArrow,500, 200);
        batch.end();
}
```

The TLArrow draws fine, but the tools does not. I logged tools.toString() and it returned a (seemingly) valid storage location

Comment: Can you describe how the result is different compared to what you are expecting - maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. When a PNG gets stored, the invisible pixels are just stored as all black images. I assume when it gets passed on to GDX, it just ignores all black pixels, effectively drawing nothing if the PNG is all black with invisible sections. Have not yet figured out a workaround, will be using non-black images from now on unless someone knows an alternative? It worked before so there must be something that can be done